# headset bluetooth (nokia) button recive call Recive Android >4.0

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bluetooth

I search answer to my problem inside stackoverflow and I seen a lot of information but I have not found a solution to my problem.
I try to recive button nokia headset bluetooth to call recive.

In Manifest I have:

```
 <receiver android:name=".ButtonBroadcastReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000000000">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            <action android:name="android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Next I have class

```
public class ButtonBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


    public ButtonBroadcastReceiver() {
        super();
    }
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.v("TTT", "KJEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE");
        if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            /* handle media button intent here by reading contents */
            /* of EXTRA_KEY_EVENT to know which key was pressed    */
        }
    }
}
```

And in activity inside onCreate I use

```
  mAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        ComponentName  mediaButtonReceiver = new ComponentName(getPackageName(), ButtonBroadcastReceiver.class.getName());

        mAudioManager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mediaButtonReceiver);
```

When I use + or - to volue up/down it works! (in log i have my message) but when I try to click button to recive call log is clean.

Comment: once i had a similar problem. I tried to overwrite the PowerButton, but it is blocked for security purposes. Maybe that is the same with your Button!!

Comment: How you solved your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by catching the event that is triggered when the PowerButton gets pressed. In this case it was the SCREEN_ON-flag.   here: [capture hard-button events when phone is locked?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18330386/2074990)

Comment: but how to detect recive button media using action screen_on screen_off? This action can detect event when phone screen is off/on. How to detect my button? button media (I thing so) witch use to call (using bluetooth headset)

Comment: the idea was to look up which event gets fired when you press your button. if you find it, you can use it to trigger your stuff.

Comment: Good idea but still not solved my problem. Screen_on/off not detect press this button....

Comment: First of all i would try to find out if the "call receive"-button is really free to Override. It might be protected for security-reasons (like the powerButton).

Comment: Ok but you know any method to check this?